# XSLT 1.0 Wrap first element and all following siblings

Tags: xslt-1.0

I'm attempting to wrap all `<list>` elements in a `<div>`.  The `<list>` elements are all siblings of each other.  I figured matching the first element and applying templates to all it and all of it's siblings within a `<div>` would be sufficient, but I appear to be missing something here.

I have the following XML:

```
<section.body>
    <para>
        <list>
            ...
        </list>
        <list>
            ...
        </list>
        <list>
            ...
        </list>
    </para>
</section.body>
```

And the following xslt:

```
<xsl:template match="section.body/para/list[1]">
  <div>
      <xsl:attribute name="class">
          <xsl:value-of select="'&listWrapperClass;'"/>
      </xsl:attribute>

      <xsl:apply-templates select=".|following-sibling::list"/>
  </div>
</xsl:template>
```

With desired results:

```
<div class="sectionClass">
  <div class="paraClass">
      <div class="listWrapperClass">
          <div class="listClass"/>
          <div class="listClass"/>
          <div class="listClass"/>
          <div class="listClass"/>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This seems to be getting caught in a loop when attempting to apply the templates and crapping out on me.  Not really sure what I'm missing here so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="section.body">
        <div class="sectionClass">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="section.body/para">
        <div class="paraClass">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="section.body/para/list[1]">
        <div>
            <xsl:attribute name="class">
                <xsl:value-of select="'listWrapperClass'"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <div class="listClass">
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </div>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::list" mode="group"/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="section.body/para/list[position()!=1]"/>

    <xsl:template match="section.body/para/list[position()!=1]" mode="group">
        <div>
            <xsl:attribute name="class">
                <xsl:value-of select="'listClass'"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to your XML input, produces:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<div class="sectionClass">
    <div class="paraClass">
        <div class="listWrapperClass">
            <div class="listClass"> ... </div>
            <div class="listClass"> ... </div>
            <div class="listClass"> ... </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect!  That was exactly what I needed.  I'm fairly new to XSLT and this pointed me in the right direction about a few things I was not understanding.  Thanks!